# How can I change a form's color and size in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change a form's color and size in C#?

```
  // something like
  Form1.BackColor = Color.Red;  
  From1.size = 1600,900;
```

Comment: in what scope do you need it done?

Comment: people on here should not give users answers right off the bat unless the OP attempts to try or research such a simple problem such as this.. how else will they learn if others keep giving them the solution.. Google search would have yielded the answer immediately WOW

Comment: even if you dont know about the good articles or websites about any topic atleast you know about google and microsoft. First see the documentation at microsoft website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
this.BackColor = Color.Red;
this.Size = new Size(1600, 900);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating an instance of the form:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();

form.BackColor = Color.Red;
form.Size = new Size(1600,900);

form.Show();
```

Comment: this is a better solution in my opinion.. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
 Form1.BackColor = Color.Red;
 Form1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(1600, 900);
 Form1.Invalidate();
```

Invalidate will cause the form to redraw itself

Comment: Why is invalidate required in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
this.Size = new Size(100, 100)
```